# Airdrop Mechanism

Tags: smart-contract, native-assets, cardano-address

I'm trying to find information about native token Airdrops. What is the mechanism?
For example, the user send 5 ADA to the wallet of the project and the smart contract will send you back (2.5 x Amount of ADA) of $NATIVETOKENS.
Is there a simple mechanism for this or it needs a smart contract?
How are distributed for example the Meld Tokens? Or the WMT?

Answer (score 1):

I was also searching for this info, but I was not able to find the answer how this is done. Same mechanism is used for an example for the Spacecoins or the newest one Hosky. I do not think you need smart contract for this but I am not sure.

I think this is simply done by the bash script running on some server with synced wallet. You can basically monitor your wallet, once you will receive the ADA you can filter the wallet ID using cli and construct outgoing transaction. And that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's basically a vending machine script.  There are some scripts available in github

Comment: Can you please give some examples and post a few links? Short answers get flagged as the low-quality posts.